# Are there any plans for ROI Pooling layer in tensorflow for object detection?

Tags: tensorflow

I know this question has been asked several times before but I didn't find much on google except a few packages written by several authors. In any case is there any plan of including the roi pooling layer (officially) in tensorflow as it is a vital component for object detection and other tasks and not having access to it is a pain while using tensorflow.

Any comments or alternate implementation (if verified) are welcomed.

Comment: It is a vital component for fast(er) r-cnn, not for object detection. There are other methods that don't use it - have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.10012

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about this paper and I will go through it. Yes I know recently YOLO and SSD detector have been proposed that are able to do detection without requiring explicit regions. But ROI pooling can also be seen as a standard module to pool features in a conv layer based on its location in the actual image space. This has uses beyond object detection e.g. recent work on visual referencing.

Comment: Again thanks for sending this paper @etarion as I see that roi pooling has been implemented using resize-crop procedure on the feature maps. I can see that it is another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to find answer to my question with the paper above. You can use tf.image.crop_and_resize function to crop any part of the network and resize it. Similar to ROI pooling you can crop a bounding box (scale it down by the number of downsampling steps e.g. 32 in VGG16) and resize it to NxN (e.g. 7x7 in VGG16) which can then be fed to the Fully Connected layer.

Comment: IN the given hardware iam not able to use the tf.image.crop_and_resize. IS there any alternative to that ?